# RSelenium: Error in if (file.access(phantompath, 1) < 0) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, rselenium, rsdriver

I'd like to get RSelenium running to help with some rvest web scraping. On my Windows 10 OS, when I run

```
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver()
```

I get the following:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:

BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in if (file.access(phantompath, 1) < 0) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

What could be causing this error? I also tried using `RSelenium` with docker to no avail. And when I tried this (based on a related SO post):

`binman::rm_platform("phantomjs") wdman::selenium(retcommand = TRUE)`

I received this error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid
```

Any insight much appreciated.

Comment: Try `driver = rsDriver(
     port = 4847L,
       browser = c("firefox"))`

Comment: Thanks but that results in the following error:

`Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - The token supplied to the function is invalid}`

Comment: The error is common problem i think when googled i got many results.

Comment: I'm an R newbie and really don't know what to do now that I can't get RSelenium to work. As far as I can tell RSelenium is the only available option for scraping JS pages with rvest.